# A lemma in approximating sequences

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

Consider the circle $\mathbb{T}^1= \frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$. We represent it as a union of disjoint subsegments $M_j=[t_j,t_{j+1})$, $j = 0, \cdots, n$, $t_0=t_n$ and define the map $S$ by the formula
\begin{align}
S(t)=t+c_j \quad \text{mod 1}, \quad t\in M_j
\end{align}
Here $c_j$ are real values. Such map is called interval translation map.

Consider sequences $\{t_k^m\}$ and $\{c_k^m\}$ of rational numbers that converge to $t_k$ and $c_k$ respectively. Let $S_m$ be corresponding mappings.

Lemma: The approximating sequences $\{t_k^m\}$ and $\{c_k^m\}$ may be selected so that the following statement is true. Assume that numbers $i,j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$: $i\neq j$, and $l_1, \cdots ,l_n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ are such that
\begin{align}
t_j-t_i=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nl_kc_k. \quad *
\end{align}
Then for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{align}
t_j^m-t_i^m = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n l_k c_k^m
\end{align}

Proof: Let $L$ be the space of all values $t_j$ and $c_j$ satisfying all equations $*$ that are true for the considered values of parameters. Since all coefficients $l_k$ are integers, points with rational coordinates are dense in $L$.

---

My questions about the proof :

At first I emphasize that this lemma and its proof is in "Invariant measures for interval translations" written by S.kryzhevich.

I'm a little confused in this proof of the lemma.

If I understood right $L:=\{t_j, c_j ;\quad t_j-t_i=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nl_k c_k\}$ which $t_j \in M_j$ and $c_j$ could be any real numbers. Now since $l_k$ are integers so $l_k c_k^m$ are still rational numbers even since $t_j^m , t_i^m$ are rational and since rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so points with rational coordinates are dense in $L$. Why being dense in $L$ guarantees the validation of the proof?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seem to make much sense, There are conditions in order to get an interval exchange map and the author is either unaware of them or forgot to include them. There are also inaccuracies concerning sequences (finite? or infinite? the author does not seem to care).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your question.

The cxdimension of the space $L$ is finite (this is a subspace of ${\mathbb R}^N$ for some $N$.

Let us assume for simplicity that $codim L=1$ i.e. there is only one equation (*). Then one of coordinates (let it be $c_{n}$) can be expressed
as
$$c_n=a_1 t_1+\ldots+ a_n t_n+b_1 c_1+\ldots b_{n-1} c_{n-1}$$
with all coefficients $a_j$ and $b_j$ being rational.

Then the converging sequence may be 'projected' to the space $L$ as follows: we replace the value $c_n^{m}$ with
$$a_1 t_1^m+\ldots+ a_n t_n^m+b_1 c_1^m+\ldots b_{n-1} c_{n-1}^m.$$

The case $codim L >1$ can be considered similarly.

Sincerely yours,
Sergey

Comment: Such a pleasure that the writer himself answers me, I'm just so lucky.

 Thanks a lot professor.